# readline loop commenting in an empty space Python

Tags: python, readline

The picture shows that everything else works properly instead there is an empty space in the code and that makes the program print "was invalid." I have no idea where the empty space comes from, any suggestions?

[image]

```
selec1 = open("strings.txt","r")
selec2 = "bob"
while selec2:
    selec2 = selec1.readline().replace("\n","")
    if selec2.isalnum() == True:
        print(selec2,"was ok.")
    if selec2.isalnum() == False:
        print(selec2,"was invalid.")
```

Comment: .strip() perhaps

Comment: It looks like that the last line of the file is an empty line. Try to exclude that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this iterating by-lines, which may be what's intended

For example

```py
with open("strings.txt") as fh:  # close file when leaving scope
    for line in fh:              # file-likes are iterable by-lines
        line = line.strip()      # remove trailing newline
        print("{} was {}.".format(line, "ok" if line.isalnum() else "invalid"))
```

This does a few helpful things

- using `with open()` instead of `open()` will close the file when you're done with it
- calling `.strip()` on the line (as noted in comments) will remove trailing newline chars from lines more easily than replacing them
- `open()` returns a file-like, which is already iterable by-lines (so you can simply write a structure like `for x in y`) and will omit a [trailing final line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)
- you can make a structure like `"a" if something else "b"` to simplify some flows